# How can I specify source files for Cabal/Stack package with more control than just hs-source-dirs/source-dirs?

Tags: haskell, testing, cabal, haskell-stack

I have a Haskell project that is built using Stack (therefore Cabal).
Right now I have src/ directory and tests/ directory, however I would like to mix tests together with the source files, which means everything would go to src/ directory.

For that, I would need to define my `tests` build-info source files to be files in src/ that have .test.hs extension.
However, it seems that only choice for defining source files is `source-dirs` in stack or `hs-source-dirs` in cabal, meaning that I have to put `src` as `source-dirs`, which seems wrong because it is also capturing the normal source files then.

This is what part of my package.yaml:

```
tests:
  myapp-test:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ...
```

While I would like it to be smth like:

```
tests:
  myapp-test:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-files:         src/**/*.test.hs
    ...
```

Is there any option like that, like source-files, or any other way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do it. I recommend you stick to the convention of keeping source and tests in separate directories. If you want to package together a small contained set of modules and tests, just make another library!

Comment: Can you say why you want to mix the files in one directory? Perhaps we can suggest an alternative that addresses your concerns.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for trying to find a solution!
I have been lately working a lot in javascript and convention there is to keep test files next to the source files. I also worked before on project where those were split in different directory structures, so I can compare both. I liked better when they are next to source files because it is easier to find and open them -> I don't need to navigate two parallel directory structures.. I am sure there are pros and cons, but I found this to be smth I like/prefer. But I would love to hear different opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Separate `src` and `tests` dir is convention, but not a must.
`hs-source-dirs` defaults to `.`.

Cabal finds all source files by itself.
Otherwise there is `extra-source-files`.

Your choice is on the module level: `exposed-modules`, `other-modules`.
You can use them for libraries and executables.

In your `.cabal` file:

- Use one `executable <name>` entry per executable.
  `main-is` is the file with `module Main where ...`.
- Use one `library <name>` per library.
- Use one `test-suite <name>` entry per test app.

  - `type` is required (e.g. `type: exitcode-stdio-1.0`).
  - `main-is` is the test file.
  - `ghc-options:         -main-is <your.hs>`
  - in the test files have also a

  ```
    main :: IO ()
    main = hspec spec -- or: spec1 >> spec2
  ```

Cabal usage:

```
  cabal new-build
  cabal new-test [<which test>]
  cabal new-run <file without path>
```

Deep in `dist-newstyle` you will find

- the executables under an `x` directory
- the test executables under a `t` directory
- the library `.so` files under a `l` directory

Links:

- (cabal documents) [https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#autogenerated-modules-and-includes]
- example projects:
  (hspec-example)[https://github.com/hspec/hspec-example/blob/master/strip.cabal]
  (tasty-cabal-example-tests) [https://github.com/willprice/haskell-cabal-example-tests/blob/master/quickcheck-example.cabal]
- cabal sources: `*.cabal`, `cabal/Cabal/doc/buildinfo-fields-reference.rst`